# Google Compute Engine: Adding SSH but can't connect like in their video

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, filezilla

OK I need help.

I have created a simple instance with Google Compute Engine, and I have added SSH keys through their META DATA section. But every time I try to log in with Putty (I can do it with their console) I get Permission denied (publickey)

Even when I log in with their browser console , I can see all the users I created with WEB UI, and public keys in authorized_keys

However I can't SSH even though my private keys are in my .ssh

I did all the checked and my ssh is enabled by default
http://screencast.com/t/zI9vDr2s

Comment: Which of the four keys on the screenshot are you trying to use and with what account?

Comment: Also show us a PuTTY event log (right click PuTTY window title)

Comment: `Status: Connecting to 104.197.97.96...
Response: fzSftp started, protocol_version=3
Command: keyfile "C:\Users\adnan\.ssh\tuned_filezilla.ppk"
Command: keyfile "C:\Users\adnan\.ssh\private filezilla - Copy.ppk"
Command: open "adnan@104.197.97.96" 22
Error: ssh_init: Host does not exist
Error: Could not connect to server`

I managed to connect with the latest one `adnan`  through SSH, however I can't connect with Filezilla to move files... 

The message at the top is what is shown

Comment: That's a completely different question now. This is Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing was that I was accessing the site via IP, since for me the site's DNS wasn't propagated at the moment. nevertheless I tried placing domain name instead of IP and it worked. Weird because I still can't access the site via domain ... and my neighbor can.